# Insert into Mysql Database from Android. Where i repair

Tags: php, android, mysql, insert

I'm writing an application to insert data into a MySQL database. I wrote the sql query in PHP and when i enter values in the android application, i don't seen any errors in the log cat but the values aren't getting stored in the database.
php code:

```
<?php
    $baglan=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    $sec=mysql_select_db("bitirme",$baglan);

    $yemek=$_POST['yemek'];
    $icecek=$_POST['icecek'];
    $tatli=$_POST['tatli'];

    mysql_query("insert into deneme(yemek,icecek,tatli) values('{$yemek}','${icecek}','${tatli}')");
?>
```

android code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    final StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          //  yemek = ""+ e1.getText().toString();
           // icecek = ""+ e2.getText().toString();
           // tatli = ""+e3.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yemek",e1.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("icecek",e2.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tatli",e3.getText().toString()));

            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/deneme.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                String msj="basariyla eklendi";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msj,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            }
            catch(ClientProtocolException e)
            {
                //Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                Log.e("ClientPRotocol","Log_tag");
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                //       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Log.e("Log_tag","IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           // insert();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some reason try these

1)Check Connection to server is working fine

2)Try to use some debugging on server side when you receive these variable like print these variables you are receiving from android side.

3)Try to insert some dummy data in hardcoded from in server side if that is working then if you reciving value from android that will also work.

Hope this will help